# Images not appearing in WAMP/Localhost

Tags: php, yii, localhost, wamp, server

My Project is done in Yii Framework, however i am been told by my developer that the Yii framework installation is not required.

so i have only WAMP local server installed, and here all my other  UI designs are working fine.

However this Yii framework project is showing up without the images. please see attached. [link to webpage screenshot without image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dChl.png)

Appreciate if any pointers to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: copy image url and paste some where and see what you get from it.

Comment: You have to set base_url in some config file of that framework.

Comment: look like resources problem not in cache, or maybe declare assets as `--symlink`. Please contact your developer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone, it is working perfectly fine in my XAMP windows platform, but not working in WAMP laptop. so i am not sure if this problem is related to Yii development or just Apache error, does this explain better.

Comment: Are your XAMPP and WAMPServer configured the same??

Comment: yes, default configuration for both, for XAMPP changed the file "httpd-vhosts.conf". but having done the same in WAMP it does does not work.

Comment: Show your Virtual Host definition used in WAMPServer and XAMPP. Thats the most likely place for an error that would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of reason for your problem. I think you should use the developer tool of chrome or firefox(like the foto below). Then you can check the url of each pic and find what's wrong with those pics.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working perfectly fine in my XAMP windows platform, but not working in WAMP laptop. so i am not sure if this problem is related to Yii development or just Apache error, does this explain better.  any other thougt